# Remove Ui Element and Update 2d array from tapped event handler c# xaml.cs uwp

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp, event-handling, uwp-xaml

Hello I'm having a problem with a test game i am writing with uwp.

At the moment i have a grid as shown below.
[image: Game Area]

I am using a grid that is generated at compile time in the mainPage.xaml.cs file.

```
<Page
x:Class="Solitaire.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Solitaire"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="grdRoot"  Background="DarkBlue">


    <Grid x:Name="grdGame"  />
    <Grid x:Name="grdPieces"   />
</Grid>
```

Adding rows and coulmns to the grid

```
 private void addRowsColumns()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {

            grdPieces.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            grdPieces.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

            grdGame.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            grdGame.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }

    }
```

Adding the borders to the grdGame grid.

```
Border brdr;
    //Adapted from https://github.com/dcMobileAppsDev/ClassContainers/blob/master/ClassContainers/MainPage.xaml.cs
    private void addBorders()
    {

        int iR, iC;

        //iR set to 1 to center the board in front of the background
        for (iR = 0; iR < 7; iR++)
        {//iC set to 1 to center board
            for (iC = 0; iC < 7; iC++)
            {
                brdr = new Border();
                //name for getting the position of the peices on the board.
                brdr.Name = iR.ToString() + "_" + iC.ToString();

                //set default colour of border to balck
                brdr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

                // if modulus of iR + iC is 0, then make the square white
                if ((iR + iC) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    brdr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                }
                //remove the squares that are not needed for the game
                //colour these squares the same colour as the grid background
                //@todo need to make these references in the grid non playable.
                if ((iR < 2&& iC < 2) || (iR < 2 && iC > 4) || (iR > 4 && iC < 2) || (iR > 4 && iC > 4))
                {
                    brdr.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BurlyWood);
                }
                brdr.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, iR);
                brdr.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, iC);
                brdr.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                brdr.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                //@todo set height and width of squares not hard coded.
                brdr.Height = 100;
                brdr.Width = 100;
                //add squares to the board.

                grdGame.Children.Add(brdr);


            }

        }

    }
```

Then i have a 2d array to hold the ellipses and these are placed in the  over the border gridPieces grid. The 2d array is filled with borders and ellipses to initially start the game.

```
 Ellipse myEl;
    UIElement[,] grid;
    private void addPieces()
    {
        myEl = new Ellipse();

        grid = 
        // loop rows 
        new UIElement[7, 7] {

        {brdr,brdr,myEl,myEl,myEl,brdr,brdr},
        {brdr,brdr,myEl,myEl,myEl,brdr,brdr},
        {myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl},
        {myEl,myEl,myEl,brdr,myEl,myEl,myEl},
        {myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl,myEl},
        {brdr,brdr,myEl,brdr,myEl,brdr,brdr},
        {brdr,brdr,myEl,myEl,myEl,brdr,brdr},
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                if (!grid[i, j].Equals(brdr))
                {
                    myEl = new Ellipse
                    {
                        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver),
                        Name = i + "_" + j,
                        Tag = "peices",
                        Height = 50,
                        Width = 50
                    };
                    grid[i, j] = myEl;

                    grid[i, j].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                    grid[i, j].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);



                    grdPieces.Children.Add(myEl);
                    myEl.Tapped += myEl_Tapped;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

These three functions are then passed to the main page method to run at compile time.

```
 public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        addBorders();
        addRowsColumns();
        addPieces();

    }
```

I have a tapped event handler for the ellipses that highlights borders two squares above or below if there is an ellipse one square above or below the tapped ellipse.

Please see below for an image of what i have so far.
The red border is highlighted when the ellipse in the second top row in the white square is tapped.

[image]

And the code for the above event.

```
Ellipse moveMe;
    //Possible moves for the user to choose
    Border possible1, possible2;
    //Different possible moves to check for
    int twoSquaresDown, twoSquaresLeft,twoSquaresUp,twoSquaresRight,curRow,curCol,
        oneSquareDown,oneSquareUp,oneSquareRight,oneSquareLeft;
    //tapped event handler
    private void myEl_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Ellipse current = (Ellipse)sender;
        //moveME used in the border tapped event handler to update the positon of the ellipse
        moveMe = current;
        //set all values below for updating the position of the ellipse in the game grid
        //and for updting the peices array
        curRow = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        curCol = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        oneSquareDown = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty) + 1;
        oneSquareUp = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty) - 1;
        oneSquareRight = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty) + 1;
        oneSquareLeft = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty) - 1;
        twoSquaresDown = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty)+2;

        twoSquaresUp = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty) -2;
        twoSquaresLeft = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty) - 2;

        twoSquaresRight = (int)current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty) + 2;
        //@todo set condition for the four possible moves
        //set boudries for edge of board.


        //name for getting the position of the peices on the board.

        if (twoSquaresDown < 7)
        {
            if (grid[twoSquaresDown, curCol].Equals(brdr) && !grid[oneSquareDown, curCol].Equals(brdr))
            { ////grid = new UIElement[9, 9];
                possible1 = new Border();
                possible1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                possible1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, twoSquaresDown);
                possible1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, curCol);
                possible1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                possible1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                //@todo set height and width of squares not hard coded.
                possible1.Height = 100;
                possible1.Width = 100;
                possible1.Name = "possible1";

                grdGame.Children.Add(possible1);

                possible1.Tapped += Brdr_Tapped;
            }
        }



        //Condition for Boundry at top of board
        if (twoSquaresUp > 0)
        {
            // Condition for checking if the tapped ellipse has an ellipse above
            // it and the following square above is empty in the array
            if (grid[twoSquaresUp, curCol].Equals(brdr) && !grid[oneSquareUp, curCol].Equals(brdr))
            { 

                possible2 = new Border();
                //set the border colour to red as an option to move to
                possible2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                // set the coordinates
                possible2.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, twoSquaresUp);
                possible2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, curCol);
                possible2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                possible2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                //@todo set height and width of squares not hard coded.
                possible2.Height = 100;
                possible2.Width = 100;
                //name for removing the ellipse if the square is clicked
                possible2.Name = "possible2";
                //add the red  border to the grid
                grdGame.Children.Add(possible2);

                possible2.Tapped += Brdr_Tapped;

            }
        }
     }
```

then when the border is tapped it sends another event handler that removes the jumped ellipse and moves the original ellipse to the red square.

```
    private void Brdr_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border current = (Border)sender;


        //move the ellipse toe the tapped border
        moveMe.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, current.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty));
        moveMe.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty,current.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty));

        //GEt the name of the border that is tapped
        if (current.Name == "possible1")
        {

            //set Ellipse to be removed from the array
            myEl = (Ellipse)grid[oneSquareDown, curCol];
            //remove the ellipse from the grid
            grdPieces.Children.Remove(myEl);
            //remove both highlighted squares
            grdGame.Children.Remove(possible1);
            grdGame.Children.Remove(possible2);
            //remove tapped handler
            possible1.Tapped -= Brdr_Tapped;
            //update the array
            grid[oneSquareDown, curCol] = brdr;
            grid[twoSquaresDown, curCol] = myEl;
            grid[curRow, curCol] = brdr;
        }

        else
        // else It's possible2 border tapped
        {
            //set Ellipse to be removed from the array
            myEl = (Ellipse)grid[oneSquareUp, curCol];
            //remove the ellipse from the grid
            grdPieces.Children.Remove(myEl);
            //remove both highlighted squares
            grdGame.Children.Remove(possible1);
            grdGame.Children.Remove(possible2);

            //remove tapped handler
            possible2.Tapped -= Brdr_Tapped;
            //update the array
            grid[oneSquareUp, curCol] = brdr;
            grid[twoSquaresUp, curCol] = myEl;
            grid[curRow, curCol] = brdr;

        }
```

[image]

The array is updated when this move is done. i have the array printed out for testing and it matches what the grid is showing for the middle column.
I have left out the rest of the console print out for clarity.

[image]

This works for all pieces in upward or downward directions apart from if i try this move which is the ellipse in the third row up in the middle column after the first move.

[image]

When i tap the red border the ellipse that should be removed (the fourth row down and the middle column) but it stays on screen.

[image]

I think this could be the way i am updating the array or the way the array is initialized that is causing the problem.

Here is a printout of the column from the array.

[image]

It is printing as it should on the console but the ellipse is not removed on the screen.
The other moves on the board are working but this is causing a problem as i have to implement left and right moves also. and cant continue until i have this problem solved.

Any help you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just update the array,  but no the logic to make the UI follow the array, so you should find the ellipse to make it display or not.